# Restore SQL Server database to different server with non sysadmin user

Tags: sql-server, database-restore, database-permissions

I'm trying to restore a database from a backup into a different server using an user that is not **sysadmin** (with dbcreator server role).

According to this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190436(v=sql.105).aspx the user that restores the database is the dbOwner.

Using a **sysadmin** user I can see in the database properties that the user that restored the database is the owner, however after the restore I can't access the database.

I've already tried to add more server roles to the user (in the limit everything except **sysadmin**) and the result is always the same: I can restore the database but then I can't access it.

Is there any way of doing this without a **sysadmin** user?

Comment: Any chance you ever found a way to do this?  I just posted a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145524/database-not-accessible-after-restore

Comment: I haven't found a solution for this...We are requiring a sysadmin user to run our application that restores the database and then add permissions to the user that is used in the application that makes use of the database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  After quite a bit of experimentation and research, I came to the same conclusion.  If you are interested, there is more on the topic here - http://mattsql.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/restore-database-permissions  (scroll down to the comments section)